# Why does multiple form submit clicks not call the url multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please refer to the fiddle below.

```
<form method="get" action="/cart/add" target="top">
  <input type="text" name="q" value="">
  <input type="submit" value="Search Google">
</form>



var parent = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
var script = document.createElement("script");
var url = "http://www.google.com";

$("form[action='/cart/add']").find(':submit').click(function(event){
    script.src = url;
    parent.appendChild(script);
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nihalsharma/r6vdga95/

I have a doubt. Why not clicking the submit button multiple time hitting the url again and again? What if I want to hit my url every time I click my submit button?

Comment: Please make your actual question more clear and refer to the FAQ

Comment: His question is clear to me, he wants to know why his form isn't submitted every time he presses submit.

Comment: If you want something like that then I think the best way to do that is by using AJAX.. Here is the link: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I can hit the submit button in your jsfiddle multiple times, and it'll reload the new tab every time, so I'm not sure I understand the question

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - when I see my dev console in chrome, it has only one call to the url, even if I press the submit multiple times?

Comment: @NihalSharma that's because the submit form is reloading your page. You should see the tab/window being reloaded each time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form submission is based on the fact that you have some data, and clicking the `submit` button finalizes the form and causes the browser to load up the URL the form indicates should be loaded. Usually in the same view, so you lose your old page and get a new one, but if you use what you did, it'll open in a new tab instead.

So that's exactly what it's doing. If you click the submit button, it opens the form URL in a new tab, and clicking submit will keep (re)opening the form in (that same) tab. IF you click submit multiple times, it'll open the submission URL multiple times.

Your code does exactly what it should be doing.